# how to display the English DisplayName in .net core view instead of the localized string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a .net core project where in one of my views i have to display the 
DisplayName  in English and in Arabic in the same view
only i get one language as the view have localized resource file

i created an extension method which take the model and return the DisplayName  metadata 
actually my method and the original @html helper return one language 
here the method i hope some one can modify it so it return the original English metadata instead of the localized value

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace iSee.IHtmlHelpers
{

    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent DisplayNameForEn<TModel, TValue>(
            this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
        )
        {
            var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData, htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
            var metadata = modelExplorer.Metadata;
            var DisplayName = metadata.DisplayName;
            return new HtmlString(DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nick Polideropoulos the answer above was helpful and inspired me to find an answer for the question 
here the answer in case some one else search for

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace iSee.IHtmlHelpers
{

    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {

        public static IHtmlContent DisplayNameForLatin<TModel, TValue>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {

            var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                return new HtmlString("");
            }

            var displayAttribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();

            return new HtmlString(displayAttribute.Name);

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with code like the example below.

```
public static IHtmlContent DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,CultureInfo culture
    )
    {
        if (culture == null)
        {
            culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        }
        var displayAttribute = (expression.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member.GetCustomAttributes()
            .FirstOrDefault(tt => tt is DisplayAttribute) as DisplayAttribute;
        if (displayAttribute == null)
        {
            return new HtmlString("");
        }
        var resourceType = displayAttribute.ResourceType;
        var name = displayAttribute.Name;
        if(resourceType == null)
        {
          return new HtmlString(name);
        }
        var resourceManager = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager(resourceType);
        var displayName = resourceManager.GetString(name, culture);
        return new HtmlString(displayName);
    }
```

In general you want to take the `DisplayAttribute.ResourceType` and the `DisplayAttribute.Name` then use the Resource Manager along with the culture info of the language you want to translate it.

**EDIT 2:**

A possible Exception on .NET Core would be due to the changes on how the .resx files are used in .NET Core. Making the method above more suitable for .NET Framework applications and the `IStringLocalizer<T>` solution from the first **EDIT** more suitable for the ASP.NET Core

**EDIT:**

You can also use the `IStringLocalizer<T>` feature of ASP.NET Core find some reference here: [Globalization and Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization). For example you could update the above method to use the `IStringLocalizer`

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
var localizer = factory.Create(typeof(Startup));
var specificLoc = localizer.WithCulture(culture);
```

Comment: the first method the displayAttribute throw an exption

Comment: Thank you , your answer help me to find the solution

Comment: please modify your answer so i can accept it as the write answer

Comment: Hello. What do i need to modify ? (Sorry im kind of new on the stackoverflow answer on questions). Can you tell me the Exception that is thrown?

Comment: actually resourceType  is not null but have internal exception of invalid operation 
just am asking you to add to your answer 
the method in my answer below so i can select your answer as the write helpful answer

Comment: Hello @mohamedAli i did a new edit with some of my findings.